# I am stuck in this codes in GCC

Tags: c, pointers, reverse, c-strings, function-definition

I was testing the code in GCC in Linux. So far so good, Here is simple SLOC that i tried to achive...
After running the code output is:

```
<1>
<>
<>
```

But more impressively when i change order of printf lines giving different results...
What is wrong with this code and about this situation could you please assit me...
Thanks
Regards.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
char *vbStrReverse(char *pBuffer);
int main(){
    printf("<%s>",vbStrReverse("1"));
    printf("<%s>",vbStrReverse("123456"));
    printf("<%s>",vbStrReverse(""));
}

char *vbStrReverse(char *pBuffer){
    int size=strlen(pBuffer);
    char *ptr =(char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*size+1);
    int i;
    int ax;
    do
    {
        ax=*(pBuffer+i);
        if (ax=='\0'){
            *(ptr+i+1)='\0';
            break;
        }
        *(ptr+i)=*(pBuffer+size-i-1);
        i++;
    } while (1);
    return(ptr);
 }
```

Comment: You do not initialize `i` before you use it. The result is **undefined behavior.** (There may be other problems.)

Comment: I think `*(ptr+i+1)='\0';` is a buffer overflow; should be `*(ptr+i)='\0';`

Comment: Each call of `vbStrReverse` causes a memory leak as you do not free any of those newly allocated memory blocks.

Answer (score 0):

The function has undefined behavior.

For starters the variable `i` was not initialized

```
int i;
```

It seems you mean

```
int i = 0;
```

In this statement

```
*(ptr+i+1)='\0';
```

a garbage can be included in the array pointed to by the pointer `ptr` for example when the source string is empty and the memory beyond the allocated array will be overwritten

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
char * vbStrReverse( const char *pBuffer )
{
    size_t size = strlen( pBuffer );
    char *ptr = malloc( size + 1 );

    if ( ptr != NULL )
    {
        ptr += size;
        *ptr = '\0';

        while ( *pBuffer )
        {
            *--ptr = *pBuffer++;
        }
    }

    return ptr;
}
```